# How do I do a yielding loop with underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, settimeout

So, I want to loop through several hundred items and not block the UI thread while I process each -- altogether possibly a few seconds of work, so I'd like to yield every so often. Several books recommend a loop that looks like this:

```
function processArray(items, process, callback){
    var todo = items.concat(); //create a clone of the original
    setTimeout(function () {
        process(todo.shift());
        if (todo.length > 0) {
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, 100);
        } else {
            callback(items);
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

(ref http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1506-yielding-with-javascript-timers/ )

Last time I used a clever loop, I found out that underscore already supported it and probably had better, more stable, etc. version.  How do I do the above in underscore? _.each doesn't seem to apply, _.each doesn't appear to yield or provide options for changing the pause time.

Comment: What work are you performing? Would web workers be suitable?

Comment: For a line of business application, so it's IE 7 & 8. Specifically I'm trying to do background pre-loading of a bunch of static files on a slow network with slow clients and slow servers.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the Async library
https://github.com/caolan/async
And make `process` an asynchronous function that accepts a callback.

```
function process(item, cb){
    //replace this code block with your actual process logic
    setTimeout(function () {console.log(item); async.nextTick(cb);}, 500);
}
function processArray(items, iterator, callback){
    var todo = items.concat(); //create a clone of the original
    async.eachLimit(todo, 4, iterator, function(){ 
        //replace 4 with the desired number of simultaneous asynchronous operations
        //if `process` isn't too computationally expensive, you could try 50 
        callback(); //all done
    });
}

processArray([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], process, function(){
    console.log('all done');
});
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/izumob/1/

Comment: Um, that just changes my question from how do I do that with underscore to how do I do that with the async.js library?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an interval instead. That way, you are not calling `setTimeout` repeatedly, as well as building an anonymous function on every iteration:

```
function processArray(items, process, callback) {
  var todo = items.concat();

  //our interval "loop"
  var loop = setInterval(function () {

    process(todo.shift());

    //"break" the interval when nothing left
    if(!todo.length) {
      clearInterval(loop);
      callback(items);
    }
  }, 100);
}
```